# Can I set the label text in JavaFX using threads?

Tags: java, multithreading, javafx, nullpointerexception

I want to constantly display the current mileage of the car without clicking on any button, etc.

Thread class

```
package threads;

import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;

import static controller.GameWindowController.*;

public class MileageThread implements Runnable {


@FXML
Label mileageLabel;

@Override
public void run() {
    {
        double time = 1;
        while (true) {
            try {
                Thread.sleep(1000);
            } catch (NullPointerException | InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            getCar().setDistancePerSec((time * getCar().getCurrentCarSpeed()) / 3600);
            getCar().setCarMileage(getCar().getCarMileage() + getCar().getDistancePerSec());
            System.out.format("dziala %.3f km przebiegu %n", getCar().getCarMileage());
            mileageLabel.setText(String.valueOf(getCar().getCarMileage()));
        }
    }
}
```

}

With this record I receive:

```
Exception in thread "Thread-5" java.lang.NullPointerException
at threads.MileageThread.run(MileageThread.java:27)
```

and here is the class in which I make the thread:

```
package controller;

import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.fxml.Initializable;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.image.ImageView;
import model.VehicleStatus;
import threads.MileageThread;
import vehicles.Car;

import java.net.URL;
import java.util.ResourceBundle;

public class GameWindowController extends Thread implements Initializable, Runnable {

@FXML
ImageView smoke;

@FXML
private Label speedLabel, mileageLabel;

static Car car;

static {
    car = new Car() {
    };
}

public void accelerationButtonPushed(ActionEvent event) throws InterruptedException {
    car.accelerate();

    speedLabel.setText(String.valueOf(car.getCurrentCarSpeed()));

    smoke.setFitHeight(smoke.getX() + car.getCurrentCarSpeed());
    smoke.setFitWidth(smoke.getY() + car.getCurrentCarSpeed());

    System.out.println(car.getCurrentCarSpeed());
    System.out.println(car.getCarMileage());
    System.out.println(car.getFuel());
    System.out.println(car.getStatus());
}

public void stopCarButtonPushed(ActionEvent event) throws InterruptedException {

    if (car.getCurrentCarSpeed() == 0) {
        System.out.println("Silnik zgasl!");
    }
    car.stop();

    speedLabel.setText(String.valueOf(car.getCurrentCarSpeed()));
    smoke.setFitHeight(smoke.getX() + car.getCurrentCarSpeed());
    smoke.setFitWidth(smoke.getY() + car.getCurrentCarSpeed());

    System.out.println(car.getCurrentCarSpeed());
    System.out.println(car.getCarMileage());
    System.out.println(car.getFuel());
    System.out.println(car.getStatus());
}

public void startButtonPushed(ActionEvent event) throws InterruptedException {
    if (car.getStatus() != VehicleStatus.MOVING) {
        car.start();
    } else System.out.println("Samochod juz jest na chodzie!");

    System.out.println("Status pojazdu: " + car.getStatus());
}

@FXML
public void initialize(URL location, ResourceBundle resources) {
    smoke.setFitHeight(1);
    smoke.setFitWidth(1);

    MileageThread mileageThread = new MileageThread();
    Thread mt = new Thread(mileageThread);
    mt.start();

}

public static Car getCar() {
    return car;
}
```

}

I apologize if you find here some basic mistakes or if I misunderstood you.

I'm using a scene builder and I just want to put the text in one of the labels using MileageThread.

Comment: A [mcve] demonstrating the problem would also help.

Comment: As in stopCarButtonPushed () or accelerationCarButtonPushed (). I set there speedLabel which is my speedometer but it updates only when the button is pressed. And I want to display the waveform without the need to press the buttons, for example, the thread as above but the way in which I wrote it does not work.

Comment: Assuming proper thread-safety regarding however `Car` is updated, you can use a `Timeline` that periodically updates the `Label`. See [JavaFX periodic background task](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9966136/javafx-periodic-background-task).

Comment: Thank you very much. This article helped me. I used: PauseTransition

Comment: unrelated: get rid of all those statics ...

Comment: I need this static block to create a car automatically before calling the GameWindowController class and I want to have access to it.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to modify the user interface from a thread other than the JavaFX Application thread you must wrap it in a call to `Platform.runLater()`

```
Platform.runLater(() -> {
    userInterfaceControl.setText("New Text");
});
```

JavaFX nodes/controls/etc. can only be modified from the JavaFX Application thread.

Comment: Platform.runLater doesnt work for me. i use PauseTransition. Thank you anyway for help :)

Answer (score 1):

The solution that worked for me:

```
@FXML
    public void initialize(URL location, ResourceBundle resources) {
        PauseTransition wait = new PauseTransition(Duration.seconds(1));
    wait.setOnFinished((e) -> {
        mileageLabel.setText(String.valueOf(getCar().getCarMileage()));
        wait.playFromStart();
    });
    wait.play();
}
```

I hope that someone will help :)